# Passing an array as an argument in the update method of java observerable

Tags: java, arguments, observable, updates

I'm developing a simple client-server game in which the client once successfully logged in will notify its observer with an array containing 25 words needed to update the game. The client is sending the correct information however, the update method in the GUI is not. The update method is bellow.

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    if (arg[0].equals("true1")) {
        for(int i = 1; i <26; i++]){
           String [i] words = args[i]; // sets the words to the args 
       }

       player = new PlayerView(client, words); // creates new playerview taking the client and an array of words

       this.setContentPane(player); // sets player view to content pane
    }
}
```

When I try this I get the following error:

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object

I've tried casting the args before the if statements but this doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Define "doesn't seem to be working".

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

- check that `arg` is actually an array of Strings (String[])
- cast it to an array of Strings
- declare `words` as an array of size 25 (if I understand correctly your algorithm)
- copy indexes 1 to 25 from your arg array to the words array

This should work

```
public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
    // check that it is indeed an array
    if(arg instanceof String[]) {
        // cast it into an array
        String[] argArray = (String[]) arg;

        // make your words array
        String[] words = new String[25];
        if (argArray[0].equals("true1")) {
            for(int i=1; i<26; i++) {
                words[i-1] = argArray[i]; 
            }

            player = new PlayerView(client, words); // creates new playerview taking the client and an array of words

            this.setContentPane(player); // sets player view to content pane
        }
    }
}
```